# java.library.path misplaced at runtime on linux

Tags: java, linux, runtime, java.library.path

Setting java.library.path at runtime doesn't do anything:

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
}
}
```

I run Test (having build it previously) like this:

```
user:~$ sudo java -d64 Test -Djava.library.path=./Music/
```

The output is:

```
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

What am I doing wrong? Did this happen to anyone else?

Also, I tried to set it in the command line, with the same result:

```
user:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./Music/
user:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ./Music
user:~$ java -XshowSettings:properties
Property settings:
....
java.library.path = ./Music
    /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
    /usr/lib64
    /lib64
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

Comment: reserved property? did you try with another property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo java -Djava.library.path=./Music/ -d64 Test
```

Et voila :-) The "-D" must go **before** your programme's name.